# Parse XML to sql parameters, datetime2 and bit questions

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, xml

I have a quandary I am unable to resolve and a general question: I am parsing an XML file from a vendor and cannot modify the API output. Thanks to all the wonderful people here I manged to write the code to get it to dump the data into SQL Server 2008 R2. The one thing I cant figure on how to accomplish is converting the `<date>` node from it's current form to `datetime2` (or whatever `datetime` format you can recommend). I have tried many different ways, each one fails more miserably than the previous attempt.

The error I get is

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime2

On a separate note, I'm thinking there must be an easier way to loop through the child nodes. There are 15 more text fields and if I can get SQL server to do the heavy lifting somehow, shouldn't I be able to just loop through each of the child notes and send name/value pairs as string parameters?

Thanks in advance.

The XML:

```
<results>
    <result>
        <title>Application Developer</title>
    ...
    <date>Thu, 30 Jan 2014 14:09:00 GMT</date>
    <expired>false</expired>
</result>
```

The sp:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.StaffWriteImport
          ( 
        title ,
        ...
        jbdate ,
        expired 
       ) 
     VALUES 
      ( 
     @title ,
     ...
     @jbdate ,
     CAST(CASE @expired WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT)   
          )
```

the C#:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                {
                    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xmlDoc.LoadXml(responseFromServer);
                    XmlNodeList Xn = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//response/results/result");

                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("data source=myconnectionstring yada yada yada;"))

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, conn))
{
    foreach (XmlNode xnode in Xn)
    {
        XmlElement resultElement = (XmlElement) xnode;
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText))
        { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("title", resultElement.GetElementsByTagName("title")[0].InnerText); }  
        ...

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultElement.GetElementsByTagName("date")[0].InnerText))
        {   var dateformat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:fff";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("jbdate", resultElement.GetElementsByTagName("date")[0].InnerText); }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(resultElement.GetElementsByTagName("expired")[0].InnerText))
        { 
            int exprd = 0;
            if (resultElement.GetElementsByTagName("expired")[0].InnerText == "true") { exprd = 1; }
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("expired", exprd) ; }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        conn.Close();

    }
}
}}}
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with your dateFormat variable, you just create it. This might be one issue. Also using XDocument will make the code prettier / easier to work with. Finally, if there are lots of these results to insert, consider using TVP (table valued parameters). You'd create a DataTable of all the results and pass the whole thing once to the SP.

Comment: that was a typo in my obfuscated example. I actually have tried using it a gazillion different ways.

Comment: thank you David. Would you be able to point me to an example of XDocument that is similar to what I'm doing? I am unable to find any examples on my own. Thanx

Comment: what version of sql server are you running?

Comment: It says SQL 2008 R2 in the question...

Comment: and Im building in VS 2012 .Net 4.5

Comment: @David Khaykin sorry, just scanned the question quickly you are correct it does.

Comment: @user116923: See my answer, it should get you going in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this:

1. I'd make my stored procedure use a Table Valued Parameter to take all results at once. This feature was available as of SQL 2008 so you can use it.
2. I'd use XLinq to do the parsing, and then create a DataTable of the results (which is required to pass to the stored procedure that takes a Table Valued Parameter).

**The SQL**

I just used 3 columns here for an example, you can add all the ones you need.

```
-- This is needed to use as a parameter in an SP
CREATE TYPE XmlResultType AS TABLE 
(
    Title varchar(50),
    [Date] datetime2(7),
    Expired bit
)
GO

-- Simple stored procedure just copies results from TVP into actual table
Create Procedure usp_InsertXmlResultsByTable
(
    @XmlResultTable dbo.XmlResultType READONLY
) 
As
    Insert Into XmlResult
    Select Title, [Date], Expired
    From @XmlResultTable
```

**And example C#:**

Note I know you're calling a web service, so my example, imagine the `xml` variable is the result of your web service call. You'd use `XDocument.Parse(xml)` in either case to create the `XDocument` object.

```
        string xml = @"
            <results>
                <result>
                    <title>Application Developer</title>
                    <date>Thu, 30 Jan 2014 14:09:00 GMT</date>
                    <expired>false</expired>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <title>Incomplete</title>
                    <date></date>
                    <expired></expired>
                </result>
                <result>
                    <title>Professional Time-waster</title>
                    <date>Fri, 31 Jan 2014 18:35:00 GMT</date>
                    <expired>false</expired>
                </result>
            </results>";

        XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        // Create a DataTable that mimics the Table Valued Parameter structure.
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Columns.Add("Expired", typeof(bool));


        // Just make the code cleaner
        Func<string, string> getString = s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? null : s;
        Func<string, DateTime?> getDateTime = d => string.IsNullOrEmpty(d) ? null : (DateTime?)DateTime.Parse(d);
        Func<string, bool?> getBool = b => string.IsNullOrEmpty(b) ? null : (bool?)Convert.ToBoolean(b);

        // here we populate the table variable, using above Funcs<> to handle nulls
        // This code does assume that your date format, when present, will always be parseable.
        xDoc.Descendants("result")
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(r =>
                dt.Rows.Add(
                    getString(r.Element("title").Value),
                    getDateTime(r.Element("date").Value),
                    getBool(r.Element("expired").Value)
                )
            );

        // Now all that's left is to call the stored procedure and pass the DataTable to it
        string connString = "your connection string";
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "usp_InsertXmlResultsByTable";
            SqlParameter tableParameter = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("XmlResultTable", dt);
            tableParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

This is a slightly different approach but it will have better performance since you are only making one call to the database for an entire XML payload from the webservice. I hope this is helpful!

Comment: Thanx so much, works like a charm! It's gonna take me a week to figure out half of it, but I appreciate the way it leverages updates to .Net and SQL server!

Answer (score 0):

So you do not need to shred it on the app side. if you can fix the dates to be something sql can read you can pass the xml to sql have sql server shred it and insert it into the tables you need. This has the added benefit of only calling the stored proc once

```
  DECLARE @testXML AS XML = '<Root>
    <node>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>test</name>
    <result>cool</result>
    </node>
    <node>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>sweet</name>
    <result>uncool</result>
    </node>
    </Root>'

      SELECT i.value('(id)[1]','INT') AS id, 
           i.value('(name)[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS name,
           i.value('(result)[1]','varchar(50)') AS result
    FROM @testXML.nodes('Root/node')x(i)
```